# Windows Batch: Run command in cmd window opened by a called batch?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I want to run a batch-file A which calls/starts another batch-file B which opens a new cmd-window. Then I want to run a user-defined command in this new cmd-window. This command is only recognized after running file B or in this new cmd-window, but the call of the command itself should be written in file A (file B is set and can't be changed). How can I do this?

As far as I understand the behavior, I can't access a cmd-window opened by another batch-file. I wrote a simple test case to show you the problem, see below.

I already tried `call` and `start`. If I run batch-file B manually in a cmd-window, I can run the user defined command in the same window because the current cmd window is "updated" and the command is recognized.

Simple test case:
In this example all commands following `call scriptB.bat` in file A are ignored (probably because the commands are run in the old cmd-window which is "overridden" by the new cmd-window opened in B which is now active). How can I pass the commands, especially the user-defined one, to the new cmd-window?

scriptA.bat:

```
@echo off

echo Start script!
call scriptB.bat
%user_command%
echo End script!
pause
```

scriptB.bat:

```
@echo off

set user_command=echo USER COMMAND!
cmd
```

Output:

```
Start script!
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
*my Path*>
```

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you with this. But out of curiosity: why do you need this?

Comment: I try to set up a build server for software with Jenkins and I need to run a custom build environment / build commands via batch file. And this custom build environment opens a new cmd-window where I can run the custom build commands.

Comment: First let's be clear on terms. Nothing in your example creates a new console window. Only `start` without the `/B` option creates a new window. `cmd` just runs a new instance of the CMD shell, which will inherit the parent's console window, if any. Like any other console application, cmd.exe does not create or host the console that it uses. A console is a shared system resource that's hosted by an instance of conhost.exe in Windows 7+. A cmd.exe process does not necessarily even attach to a console.

Comment: If scriptB.bat really starts a new instance of cmd.exe like that, I think it's unfortunately written badly. It should just set up its current shell, not create a new instance of the shell. That way callers can run something like `start "" cmd /v:on /k "scriptB.bat & "!user_command!""`.

Comment: @eryksun Thanks for your response and the information :-) I found a way to bypass the creation of the shell instance in my real batch script. This "solves" my problem in a way.

Answer (score 0):

After re-reading the Q it became apparent that the user wanted to have variables set in both scripts, and then somehow over-ride the values set in Script B with those in Script A which wee being set after the fact.

That is not possible without changing Script B to be reading the info for the variable names from the registry using WMIC and having Script A use `SetX`, or by having Script A write to a file and Script B read from the file.

However, this woudl create a Race condition as Script A may be setting that values before or after Script B checks.

Further Script B can not be modified anyway, and if it could then it could just be set up to use a normal SET Command in Script A and then have script B use those variables.

Comment: By default, child processes inherit their environment from the parent. It's possible to pass a custom environment to `CreateProcessW`, which could be loaded from the registry via `CreateEnvironmentBlock`, but there's no option to do that automatically. If you start cmd.exe from the graphical shell (Explorer), it inherits the graphical shell's environment. It seems to be loading it fresh from the registry because the graphical shell, along with other top-level windows, is sent a `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` "Environment" message by setx.exe, and in response it reloads its environment.

Comment: @eryksun  Thank you for the detailed explanation on the behavior!  I hadn't known the inner workings previously, and I suspected that CMD was like-wise inheriting the Windows Shell Environment, while I was away and thinking, but I hadn't;t realized what calls were responsible for that.  This confirms that the behavior will be as I suggested after initially thinking about it some, but gives a much more detailed explanation of why.  Do you mind if I just update this answer with that info?

Comment: I don't mind, but I don't know if this problem can be solved in general. scriptB.bat, as presented by the OP, defines the user command but then runs a new instance of CMD, so any attempt to run a sequence of commands such as `cmd /v:on /c "scriptB.bat & "!user_command!""` will get stuck waiting for that shell instance to be manually exited before the rest of the command line can run. The OP apparently found a way to avoid creating the new shell instance, but then I don't see that there's any problem left to solve.

Comment: @eryksun, No there isn't a way to solve the issue, Sorry I attempted to give a possible answer, and then explain why I think it won't work, but your description of my it won't work confirms that portion and just means that the answer is it can not be done.  This is the amendment I woudl change to basically state it can't actually be done without using something to pass the variables and reading them (a file or finding the variable from the registry through Reg / WMIC for instance)

Comment: @eryksun `manually exited before the rest of the command line can run.` Well with `CMD /C`, this is true,  but not with `CMD /K`, if we are using `Start "" CMD /K ""ScriptB.bat"` then `Script A` will continue without waiting for `Script B` to finish.  I use it for parallel processing as needed, but then you woudl have a race condition for trying to read the variables you are setting after running Script B, which is not the way to go IMO, just pointing out that it's technically possible so long as you are doing that variable passing by handwave (file/reg/etc)

Comment: @eryksun  Yeah on re-read I realize he wanted to try and change the values of variables that were also being Set in Script b, by executing something externally to Script B, which is wholly untenable, and the workarounds woudl be a race condition, so the point is moot, but I do appreciate the detailed info on the inner workings of the observed behavior of the CMD instances and why cmd can't do this.  However, based on your comment, could we create a custom executable that uses the `CreateProcessW` function to start a new cmd instance, or possibly Powershell's `Start-Process`.